# Problems removing FLV seekBar component from stage in AS2 SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flvplayback, seekbar

I have an AS2 swf that loads FLV videos into a FLVPlayback component and attaches a seekBar component. When the video stops I unload the seek bar from the screen and set the FLVPlayback.seekBar = null. When another video is to be played I set up the seek bar again by attaching the seekBar component to the stage and assigning FLVPlayback.seekBar = newSeekBarInstance.

Here's my code -

(my_video = FLVPlayback component)

```
var theSeekBar = _root.attachMovie("SeekBar", "vidSeekBar", this.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.my_video.seekBar = theSeekBar;
```

When video has stopped -

```
_root.my_video.seekBar = null;
_root.vidSeekBar.handle_mc.unloadMovie();
_root.vidSeekBar.unloadMovie();
_root.vidSeekBar.removeMovieClip();
```

What Im noticing is that sometimes the seek bar is removed from the screen and sometimes it isnt? I cant seem to notice any pattern here. Has anyone had similar problems? Do I need to force garbage collection?

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer but I would be inclined to hide the seek bar rather than removing it - `_root.my_video.seekBar._visible = false;` then `_root.my_video.seekBar._visible = true;` to reveal.

Answer (score 0):

`unloadMovie()` only works for clips you have loaded with `loadMovie()`. It will not have any effect on other stage instances.

So if you have created your instance on the stage using `attachMovie()`, `removeMovieClip()` and setting the seekBar variable to null should be enough to have it garbage collected, unless you have any more references to it (perhaps some event listeners?) somewhere else.

I agree with @duncmc though: You should consider just hiding the seekbar instead of creating and removing it over and over again.